# switching a TextView to an EditText

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

The need is to make a title (TextView) tappable to edit it(EditText)...

I'm using the trick to have 1 TextView and 1 EditText next to each other in my xml layout, and then I play with .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE/VISIBLE) to visually switch them.

Since TextView and EditText are pretty close, is that possible to effectively switch one for the other?
Or does anyone have a better trick I couldn't find?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a ViewSwitcher. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214441/how-to-convert-textview-to-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have your TextView, then on click hide it. Then use Java to create a EditText in its place.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, there are two ways you could accomplish this.

Since EditText derives from TextView, you could just make the EditText not editable(`android:editable=false`) -- and then change that attribute programatically when you want to.

The second method is to use the invisible/visible switching of the EditText and TextView.

I don't think there is a big difference between the two performance wise. Its a designer decision.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But then, how can I change the editable attribute? there is no setEditable() method...

Comment: Interesting point. I hadn't thought about that. Maybe try using a text watcher -- although that seems a bit too involved.