# How to convert TextView to EditText in android?

Tags: android

I want to convert TextView into Edit Text and vice versa in a button click event in android. I don't know how to achieve this , please help if anyone knows the solution.

Regards,
Rajapandian.K

Answer (score 79):

Best to use a ViewSwitcher

```
...
    <ViewSwitcher
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_switcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clickable_text_view"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="TextViewClicked"
            android:text="@string/some_value" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hidden_edit_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/some_value" />
    </ViewSwitcher>
...
```

Then you can switch the views by

```
public void TextViewClicked() {
    ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.my_switcher);
    switcher.showNext(); //or switcher.showPrevious();
    TextView myTV = (TextView) switcher.findViewById(R.id.clickable_text_view);
    myTV.setText("value");
}
```

Comment: I honestly think out of all of them, this answer was the best. Its so much simpler. I am curious. When should this be used? I read the doc, and it says for animation type stuff. But in this case, it makes sense to use it. So is there a reason to not use it in this case?

Comment: View switcher works nicely and you have the option to add animations easily.

Comment: Nice, but add extra space in `switcher` declaration

Comment: I see you've used android:onClick="TextViewClicked", however as I'm using a Fragment, it searches the activity of that Fragment and therefore doesn't find the method. How do I fix this so it finds the method from the Fragment and not the parent activity?

Comment: @joneswah [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325551/suggested-edit-rejected-because-it-was-intended-to-address-the-author-of-the-po) may be of some interest for you.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you can have one of each and toggle their visibility.  When the button is clicked, take the text of the visible one, apply it to the invisible one, and then swap their visibility.

Comment: @MarvinLabs: +1, he was faster ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can have both in your layout and at all times have only one of them displayed. When the EditText value changes, update the hidden TextView to keep them in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it but you can (probably) use EditText and set the background to that of TextView. Then `onfocus` change you can simply swap backgrounds based on what you want to see at any given moment. I'll try to implement it and see if it'll work

Answer (score 0):

What I think best is to actually use Framelayout concept.

Such that original layout looks like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
.
.
.
</Linearlayout>
```

Place it inside Framelayout like this.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
.
.
.
</Linearlayout>

<!-- The Magic is here -->
<View

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>



</FrameLayout>
```

Here the LinearLayout will hold all your EditText View.
Also remember to make background of EditText View null.

Like this

```
<EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/editInp"
        android:hint="@string/hello_world"
        android:background="@null"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
```

or

```
<EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/editInp"
        android:hint="@string/hello_world"
        android:background="@android:drawable/transparent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
```