# How to convert a TextView to EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am fetching the data from a database and I am appending it to a TextView. When I do long click on TextView I want to convert it to an EditText.
This is how I set the data on my TextView:

```
TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.menutext);
text.setText(itemnames[position]);//comes from database append to text view
```

Now I want to define a setOnLongClickListener to convert it into a EditText.

```
text.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {                
        String edititemname=itemnames[position];
        System.out.println(edititemname);
        return true;                
    }
});
```

`edititemname` holds which item was pressed in a long click. I want to fill the same information into the EdiText. Please help me.

Comment: "i want to append edittext on same page into editext.." make no sense. what exactly you want to do?

Comment: i want press textview long time it converts edittext and append which edit text

Comment: Use this link to find one more answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39375996/4559365

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert TextView to EditText in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214441/how-to-convert-textview-to-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as I know you can't convert one to another. What you can is: Have a TextView and an EditText created in xml. EditText is hidden when TextView is showing. Then, on your listener to the onCLick you can:

```
text.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
editText.setText(edititemname);
```

The editText variable can be defined where you define the text. You have to use the `findViewById`.

Answer (score 2):

I have Tested and it is Working :

```
    final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);


    tv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv.setVisibility(4);
            final EditText et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            et2.setVisibility(1);                       
            return false;

        }
    });
```

Just Keep EditText as `android:visibility="gone"`

Comment: Just Keep both the item near, so one will hide and other will be shown

Answer (score 1):

yes you can for that create a edittext just behind the textview in long press of textView hide textView and show editext as you done hide edittext and make visible textView

as you make invisible textview set edittext text to textview text