# How to convert a Textview to EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout

When will I press the top button edit my `TextView` want to change `EditText` in android. Is it possible in android? Can anyone answer my question?

Comment: Just put an invisible EditText next to your TextView and in your button onClick just setVisibility(View.GONE) to your TextView and setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) to your EditText.

Comment: my suggestion to you is please edit your question properly format and correct the grammar  its seems like a vague question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How to convert TextView to EditText in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214441/how-to-convert-textview-to-edittext-in-android)

[How to convert a TextView to EditText in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976433/how-to-convert-a-textview-to-edittext-in-android)

you can't convert one to another. What you can is: Have a TextView and an EditText created in xml. EditText is hidden when TextView is showing. Then, on your listener to the onCLick you can:

text.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
editText.setText(edititemname);

The editText variable can be defined where you define the text. You have to use the findViewById.
share|edit|flag

answered Apr 2 '12 at 12:43
Tiago Almeida

Answer (score 2):

I think what you should do is only use an editview, and set it to editable or not by using `editText.setEnabled(false);` and `editText.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: ya its working thanks for your replay