# How to make clickable and editable Textfield in Android?

Tags: android, textfield, onclicklistener

I am working on Android application in which I want to make my textfield editable and clickable. It has multiple TextFields and EditTexts on my screen. I have "EDIT" TextField for which I want to make it clickable and after clicking I want to make other field editable and enable. Without clicking edit Textfield all of them should not be enable.

My code snippet is given below:

```
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

    fName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fnametxt);
    lName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastnameTxt);
    mailText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mailTxt);
    mobileText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobileTxt);
    dobText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dobTxt);

    fName.setText(currentUserFirstName);
    lName.setText(currentUserLastName);
    dobText.setText("");
    mobileText.setText(currentUserContactNumber);
    mailText.setText(currentUserEmail);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9976671/2274724

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't convert TextView to EditText, but you can rather use `setEnabled` property for EditText

You can use `editText.setEnabled(true);` to make the `EditText` editable.

Say you are having two edittexts as follows. And on entering data in first edittext, you need to make edittext2 editable, then you can do this:

```
EditText edittext1, edittext2;
//findViewByIds for both views

editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
        int before, int count) {
        if(s.length() != 0)
            editText2.setEnabled(true);
        else
            editText2.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Hope this gives a clue how to use it.

**EDIT:**

Don't get confused between TextField, Button, EditText.

In Android, simple read only field is TextView. Editable textbox is called EditText, and Button is plain Button.

So as per what you are saying, you want tomake EditTexts editable upon clicking of a Button.

Use this:

```
EditText edittext1, edittext2;
Button button;
//findViewByIds for all views.
buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText1.setEnabled(true);
        editText2.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have made that Textfield to EditText. I want to make one TextField "EDIT" on clicking that button i want to make all of the other EDITFIELDS to be editable. Kindly guide me here.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. It works. Last thing i want to discuss, like if i press EDIT Button it enables EDITTEXTS, and after clicking EDIT Button again it should disable every edittexts again.

Comment: Like i have done some thing like this, on first attempt it works fine but after clicking again it just returns "click1"<br/> public void onClick(View v) {
             if (clickCount == 0){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                clickCount = 1;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

Comment: Keep a boolean and put condition accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you want to edit your textfield, then its better to go with EditText. The reason is as follows

```
The TextView's editable param does make it editable (with some restrictions).
```

If you set

```
android:editable="true"
```

you can access the TextView via the D-pad, or you could add

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

to be able to gain focus on touch.

The problem is you cannot modify the existing text, and you cannot move the cursor. The text you write just gets added before the existing text.

Comment: I have made that Textfield to EditText. I want to make one TextField "EDIT" on clicking that button i want to make all of the other EDITFIELDS to be editable. Actually i am getting some data from server and i am displaying it in my editfields, so idea is that if i click "EDIT" TextField then it will make textfields editable and after clicking "EDIT" again it should make then disable again and i should update my data again.